# Metadata generation to include Organization details

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Does the current version of the package support adding the Organization information as part of the metadata? I could not find it in the example/model. If so, where can I find it?

If not, are there any plans on adding this in the near future?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add [contact persons](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp/Controllers/MetadataController.cs#L53), and add a company name for each.

*** EDITED ***

ITfoxtec Identity SAML2 [version 4.10.8](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/releases/tag/4.10.8) support organization in metadata.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not really the <Organization> object I am looking for. The IdP requires that the object is present in the metadata (altho it is optional from a SAML perspective).

Comment: Okay, and you are correct. You are welcome to do a pull request (https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2) where you add the <Organization> element to the metadata. I'll then publish a new version.

Comment: Could you please have a look at this then? https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/pull/166

Comment: Yes, I hope to have a release ready this week.